# What is the difference between `db` command and `show dbs` command in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

In `mongo` shell when I run the code `db` it only shows `test` and when I run the `show dbs` then I see

```
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

What's the difference between the two command and why there are two different output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db` shows the current selected db in which queries are ran against (from `use <db>`). `show dbs` shows the available databases on the server.

Read more from: [mongo Shell Quick Reference.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/)